# Where is the $content of a page build?

Tags: 7

I would like to add something to my `$content` variable to add on my node template file, but where is this variable composed? I assume it's in the template.php file but what specific function composes the content of the `$content` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the `$content` variable that is available in [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7), its value is set in [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) from the following code:

```
  // Helpful $content variable for templates.
  $variables += array('content' => array());
  foreach (element_children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['content'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }
```

`$variables['content']` is then passed to [field_attach_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_preprocess/7).

```
  // Make the field variables available with the appropriate language.
  field_attach_preprocess('node', $node, $variables['content'], $variables);
```

To alter the content of the `$content` variable, you can implement [hook_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) (in a theme, or a module), or [hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter/7).

Remember that what in a template file is `$content`, in other places is `$variables['content']`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. The hook you gave me did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In template.php write this function

> function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) {   // $variables will
>   contain that content variable }

of you can use

> function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {    // $variables will
>   contain that content variable }